# How to switch tabs and pushViewController at the same time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I have two tabs in my app, the left tab is a normal UIViewController, right tab is a navigation controller with a table view inside it. I'd like to allow the user to press a button on the left tab and jump to a specific detail view that belongs to a specific row in the table view on the right tab.

In the table view itself I have no problems displaying a specific detail view eg:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:theView animated:YES];
```

and I can also jump tabs using

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1; // 1= right tab
```

but I cant figure out how to do both. I've tried

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1; // 1= right tab
// alloc and init theView here
[self.navigationController pushViewController:theView animated:YES];
```

but that doesnt work.

EDIT:

when I try the above code it just switches tab but doesnt push the view.

I also tried what criscokid suggested but nothing happens at all.

EDIT 2:

Trying to explain whats on each tab:

```
Root (Tab Bar Controller)  
|  
--(Left Tab)-- UIViewController (I want to go from here...)  
|  
--(Right Tab)---UINavigationController  
             |  
             ---UITableViewController  
                 |  
                 ----UIViewController (...to here) 
                      ^ specific view with data from specific row
                        in table view (that is 'theView' from above)
```

Answer (score 4):

For me the correct way was:

```
 UINavigationController * navigationController = (UINavigationController *) [[self tabBarController] selectedViewController];
 [navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

criscokid's answer has one redundant call to `navigationController`.
That's because your `selectedViewController` is actually a `UINavigationViewController`.

Comment: I was making the same mistake with the redundant call. This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are switching the tab bar and pushing the ViewController onto the navigation controller stack in the same method, you wouldn't want to use self.navigationController. If I understand correctly you want to add it to a navigationController on the right tab. I believe you would want to use:

```
[[[[self tabBarController] selectedViewController] navigationController] pushViewController:theView animated:YES];
```

Comment: That doesnt work for me. If i understand your code correctly, you call the pushview on the navigation controller thats supposed to be the parent of the currently selected viewcontroller in the tab bar. However there is no parent navigation controller as it is only on the right tab.

Comment: Can you trying explaining again what is on each tab?